# Is it possible to chain-overload constructors in PHP?

Tags: php, constructor, constructor-chaining

This is a made up example, it becomes much more useful when there are a lot of parameters.

This would let the caller use either `new Person("Jim", 1950, 10, 2)` or `new Person("Jim", datetimeobj)`. I know about optional parameters, that's not what I'm looking for here.

In C# I can do:

```
public Person(string name, int birthyear, int birthmonth, int birthday)
    :this(name, new DateTime(birthyear, birthmonth, birthday)){ }

public Person(string name, DateTime birthdate)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
}
```

Can I do a similar thing in PHP? Something like:

```
function __construct($name, $birthyear, $birthmonth, $birthday)
{
    $date = new DateTime("{$birthyear}\\{$birthmonth}\\{$birthyear}");
    __construct($name, $date);
}

function __construct($name, $birthdate)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->birthdate = $birthdate;
}
```

If this isn't possible, what is a good alternative?

Comment: @phpdev similar idea, but no. Calling another constructor of the same class. oh, you're gone, well now I just feel awkward...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that I'd be using named/alternative constructors/factories or whatever else you want to call them:

```
class Foo {

   ...

   public function __construct($foo, DateTime $bar) {
       ...
   }

   public static function fromYmd($foo, $year, $month, $day) {
       return new self($foo, new DateTime("$year-$month-$day"));
   }

}

$foo1 = new Foo('foo', $dateTimeObject);
$foo2 = Foo::fromYmd('foo', 2012, 2, 25);
```

There should be one canonical constructor, but you can have as many alternative constructors as convenience wrappers that all refer back to the canonical one. Or you can set alternative values in these alternative constructors that you don't usually set in the regular one:

```
class Foo {

    protected $bar = 'default';

    public static function withBar($bar) {
        $foo = new self;
        $foo->bar = $bar;
        return $foo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly the same, but you can manipulate with number of arguments in constructor, count them or check their types and call the corresponding functions. As example:

```
class MultipleConstructor {
  function __construct() {
     $args =  func_get_args();
     $construct = '__construct' . func_num_args();
     if (method_exists($this, $construct))
        call_user_func_array(array($this, $construct), $args);  
  } 

  private function __construct1($var1)
  {
      echo 'Constructor with 1 argument: ' . $var1;
  }

  private function __construct2($var1, $var2)
  {
      echo 'Constructor with 2 arguments: ' . $var1 . ' and ' . $var2;
  }

}

$pt = new MultipleConstructor(1);
$pt = new MultipleConstructor(2,3);
```

Comment: Interesting, so in `__construct` I could set all the "same/duplicate" parameters, `name` in my example. and in the `__constructN` I would set the "extra/different" parameters. That could work.